# how can I add a button chatbox header section in conversejs?

Tags: popupwindow, converse.js

I want to stream video to my users while they are chatting. I am wondering what should I do to add a button in the `Header Section` of the chat panel so that the user can see a video in a modal dialog box when he clicks on the button?
I changed the template to add the button- that was not a problem. How can I configure the objects so that I can show the video from my server?
I also saw that there is a template called `video.html`. Can I use this to launch and show my video content?
All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to [write your own Converse plugin](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/plugin_development.html) and then create a new modal instance that extends `_converse.BootstrapModal`.

Take a look at the [RoomDetailsModal](https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js/blob/9bc8bdf34c3b5633ade7acd06b97778e32839816/src/converse-muc-views.js#L477) as an example of how to do this.

To show the modal, you'll need to add an event handler to the ChatRoomView (or ChatBoxView). For example, [here's the handler for the RoomDetailsModal](https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js/blob/9bc8bdf34c3b5633ade7acd06b97778e32839816/src/converse-muc-views.js#L513).

If you're doing all of this in your own plugin (as you should), then you should add do all of that in the [overrides](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/plugin_development.html#overrides) section of the plugin.

Comment: I actually then emulated the process of telephone button in the toolbar section. Created a new <li> link in toolbar.html and then added the necessary handlers in chat_view.js and built and and could invoke the popup of the box in the one -one chat window. however it is not working in the multichat room. Are there any specific events i should wait for in MUC case before loading my dialog in the initialize function of the plugin. I can post the codes here.

Comment: The MUC has its own view, so you need to do the same for the ChatroomView. Read the source code, it'll become clear to you.

Comment: thanks for the lead. I solved the MUC case, its working fine now. I will look into the RoomsDetails Modal . if there are any issues will get back to you.